# Python: Two Windows Opening

Tags: python, user-interface

ok so for the past two weeks or so, ive been learning python as it is extremely simple to comprehend and a very handy method of creating a GUI for a program. However i have three problems.

First, when i open my .py file a command window opens , and then my program opens on top of that. Is there a way to just open the program? (and not the command window)

Second, ive been eagerly searching for a simple method of compiling (or "interpreting") 
my .py filesinto .exe files. ive come across a few people saying that the program called **py2exe**  is the best method, however i cant get it to work... Are there any easier methods for compiling python source codes into executable files?

Third, can anyone refer me to a site with a list of modules for python, along with their descriptions and.or examples? this would greatly help me as i tried using the built in help commands in the python command line, but i find that too generic, like it gives the syntax but no examples of what applications each command/module has.

**P.S: Just wondering, is there a site that offers example programs (and their source codes) that were made with python that i could take a look at to better understand this language?
(examples: Python Games, Python GUI applications, Python Questionaires, Any Python Programs/applications that demonstrate the language's usefulness)**

**INFORMATION:**

- OS: WINDOWS 7: Ultimate Edition
- Python Version: 2.6

---

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: by the way, for future reference how do i create a bounty and what are the limitations on it?

Comment: Are you using the tkinter GUI library? This is included with Python and is commonly used, but is only one of several ways to code GUI apps with Python. Personally, I'm a fan of wxPython.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Right now you're pretty much all over the place and we can't really give you an answer. Read the FAQ to learn about bounties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the command window from opening, you can save it as a .pyw file, as opposed to the usual .py. As for converting to exe, py2exe works best for me, I know there are several others, but not as fully developed as py2exe is. Python.org should contain a list of most modules. The same results could easily be procured by googling python modules.
EDIT: 
Also, as for the gui, I have found that I personally like pyqt and tkinter best.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` to run your program.
2. I use `cx_freeze`; docs on [their website](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).
3. [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi)

Comment: cx_freeze wont work, it opens and then it closes again, and the documents dont really explain much...

Comment: could you tell me what i need to type into the python.exe command line, in order to compile a .py or .pyw file into a .exe file easily? (having to remember parameters and command options drive me crazy)

Comment: @daniel: `cxfreeze <file>.py --target-dir <dist>`. After installing `cx_freeze`, the script will be in your Scripts directory.

Comment: Ok two questions, where it says dist, do i put the output directory? and after i install cx_freeze is that all i have to do? or do i have to import it or something...

Comment: @daniel: yes. In fact, I believe you should be able to leave it out entirely. And that is all you have to do for basic usage. For more advanced stuff, you can control `cx_freeze` using Python by importing it, but that's all in the docs.

Comment: ok so if i had a file "hello.py" that had a gui in it, could i still compile it by using cxfreeze hello.py F:\script\python  ?

Comment: @daniel: I meant leave out the entire option, not just the name! I believe just `cxfreeze hello.py` would work, or else `cxfreeze hello.py --target-dist F:/script/Python`. But can't you just try it and see if it works?